# How to get 'alt' of image in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table getting data from database. There are 'yes' and 'no' values inside database table but instead of yes and no I want to print image and then be able to modify it just by clicking on image to change from yes to no. Here is my table:

```
<div class="test2"></div>
<table id="admin_table" class="quartz-table">
<thead class="head">
  <tr>
    <th class="sorter-false">Del</th>
    <th class="sorter-false">Count</th>
    <th class="sorter-false">Driver</th>
    <th class="sorter-false">SubDriver</th>
    <th class="sorter-false">Skills</th>
    <th class="sorter-false"><span class='vert'>Project Captain</span></th>
    <th class="sorter-false"><span class='vert'>Supervisor</span></th>
    <th class="sorter-false"><span class='vert'>Checker</span></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td class="delete_row"><a href="#" class="link_del" id="<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>"> <img alt="" src="imagesAssessment/delete.png"></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $count++ ?></td>
    <td class="editable_skl" contenteditable="false" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'driver','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["driver"]; ?></td>
    <td class="editable_skl" contenteditable="false" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'subdriver','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["subdriver"]; ?></td>
    <td class="editable_skl" contenteditable="false" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'skills','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["skills"]; ?></td>
    <td class="prcpt" onclick="saveToDatabase(this,'Project Captain','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" >
    <?php     
        if($faq[$k]["Project Captain"] == 'yes')
            { echo '<img alt="yes" src="imagesAssessment/yes.png">' ; }
        else{ echo '<img alt="no" src="imagesAssessment/no.png">'; }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td class="spr" onclick="saveToDatabase(this,'Supervisor','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" >
    <?php     
        if($faq[$k]["Supervisor"] == 'yes')
            { echo '<img alt="yes" src="imagesAssessment/yes.png">'; }
        else{ echo '<img alt="no" src="imagesAssessment/no.png">'; }
    ?>
    </td>   
    <td class="chk" onclick="saveToDatabase(this,'Checker','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" >
    <?php     
        if($faq[$k]["Checker"] == 'yes')
            { echo '<img alt="yes" src="imagesAssessment/yes.png">'; }
        else{ echo '<img alt="no" src="imagesAssessment/no.png">'; }
    ?>
    </td>                                   
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to change data on click so I need to get value of 'alt' and then pass it to ajax, but first I just want to print alt value to check if it works:

```
function showEdit(editableObj) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#4D5B6D");
    $(".header_hide_show").css('visibility', 'visible');
}
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
    var department = $('#info').val()

$('.test2').html(editableObj.attr('alt'));
    /*$.ajax({
        url: "comAssessment/hr_config_skill_edit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'department='+department+'&column='+column+'&editval='+answer+'&id='+id,
        success: function(data){
            $(editableObj).css("background","#4D5B6D");
            //$('.test2').html(data);
        }        
    });*/
}
```

Is there a way to get alt of image for editableObj?

Comment: Remove all the on*="" and use jquery click/blur events then use `$(this).attr('alt');` to get the "alt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editableObj is this = td, you need to find image, try below:

```
var alt = $(editableObj).find("img").attr("alt");
```

But better to use data attributes.

```
<img data-status="yes"/>
.attr("data-status");
```

But anyway ...

Comment: yeah, got it after I post it. anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the poc code to get the desired image alt

```html
<!--Q. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709630/how-to-get-alt-of-image-in-jquery-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>How to get 'alt' of image in jquery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="../lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        function saveToDatabase(td) {
            var $dataTr = $(td).parent();//get the clicked td tr

            //container.find('html_tag.class')

            //get Project Captain Img alt
            console.log($dataTr.find('img.prcpt').attr('alt'));

            //get Supervisor Img alt
            console.log($dataTr.find('img.spr').attr('alt'));

            //get Checker Img alt
            console.log($dataTr.find('img.chk').attr('alt'));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Image 1</td>
                <td>Image 2</td>
                <td>Image 3</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="saveToDatabase(this);"><u>Emp 1</u></td>
                <td><img class="prcpt" alt="Img1" /></td>
                <td><img class="spr" alt="Img2" /></td>
                <td><img class="chk" alt="Img3" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```